# Calling multiple async methods within other method without returning result

Tags: c#, async-await, task-parallel-library

I am working on an `ASP.NET Core 2.2` application with `Dapper`. Virtually all methods follows the `async/await` pattern returning some sort of `Task` as a result.

Due to an issue we had with `Dapper` (I haven't personally investigated it, this part of the code I use as it is) but basically it boils down to the fact that if you want to execute in `Transaction` multiple async methods, which internally are calling other async methods and you may have several levels of nesting this way, you need to wrap all those method invocations within a single method which would be executed in a transaction.

The method that handles this is as follows:

```
public async Task<TOut> ExecuteInTransactionAsync<TOut>(
    Delegate function, 
    params object[] parameters)
{
    using (var scope = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeAsyncFlowOption.Enabled))
    {
        var result = await ((Task<TOut>)function.DynamicInvoke(parameters))
            .ConfigureAwait(false);

        scope.Complete();

        return result;
    }
}
```

So I have a very complex Entity which is saved by calling `Save` to a lot of smaller entities. This part of the code is working OK and looks like this:

```
public async SaveEntireEntity(EntityDTO entityDTO)
{
  return await _transactionProvider.ExecuteInTransactionAsync<dynamic>(
     new Func<object, Task<dynamic>>(async dto => await SaveInTransaction(dto)),
     new { Name = entityDTO.Name, Address = entityDTO.Address, Age = entityDTO.Age });
}
```

And the `SaveInTransaction` method looks like:

```
private async Task<dynamic> SaveInTransaction(dynamic dto)
{
  var entityId = await nameService.Add(dto.Name);
  await addressService.Add(dto.Address);
  await ageService.Add(dto.Age);

  return entityId;
}
```

so this is simplified, but indeed I am calling a multiple services here, which on their part are calling multiple repositories and this works fine.

**The Problem** I have is when it comes to updating the same entity within a transaction. The whole purpose of showing the `Save` logic was to point out that at the end because I have this `return entityId;` I am able to chain everything together without any problems. However, as it is right now, by default our `Update` methods are not returning anything and this is where I can't figure out how to implement the `Update` logic.

Currently I have this:

```
public async Task UpdateEntireEntity(UpdateEntityDTO, entityDTO)
{
  await _transactionProvider.ExecuteInTransactionAsync<dynamic>(
    new Func<object, Task<dynamic>>(async dto => await UpdateInTransaction(dto)),
    new { Name = entityDTO.Name, Address = entityDTO.Address, Age = entityDTO.Age });
}
```

And `UpdateInTransaction` looks like this:

```
private async Task<dynamic> UpdateInTransaction(dynamic dto)
{
  await UpdateName(dto.Name);
  await UpdateAddress(dto.Address);
  await UpdateAge(dto.Age);

  return await Task.FromResult<dynamic>(null);
}
```

This seems to work at least based on the several tests I made, however I really don't like this part:

`return await Task.FromResult<dynamic>(null);`

To me it seems like an ugly hack. The `Update` methods were thought not to return any value and this is just too artificial.

And even the worst part is that I can not figure out how implement the update method without having to return something.

One thing I've tried is to change the declaration of `UpdateInTransaction` to

`private async Task UpdateInTransaction(dynamic dto)`

and when I call the method I change it to:

```
await _transactionProvider.ExecuteInTransactionAsync<dynamic>(
new Func<object, Task>( async dto => await UpdateInTransaction(dto)..
```

But I got the following exception:

> AsyncStateMachineBox`1[System.Threading.Tasks.VoidTaskResult,
>   <fully-qualified- name>.<<UpdateEntireEntity>b__0>d] to type 
>   'System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[System.Threading.Tasks.Task]'

.
So basically that's it. Sorry for the long post. I would really appreciate some well explained answer.

Comment: Seems like you just need an overload of `ExecuteIntrasactionAsync` that only returns a `Task` and not a result.

Comment: Why do you need to return a `dynamic`-`null` after updating? Have you thought about the options of just returning nothing (here `Task`) or maybe the dynamic object that you just changed (so change `null` to `dto`)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would avoid the use of `Delegate` since it isn't typed:

```
public async Task<TOut> ExecuteInTransactionAsync<TOut>(Func<Task<TOut>> function)
{
    using (var scope = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeAsyncFlowOption.Enabled))
    {
        var result = await (function()).ConfigureAwait(false);

        scope.Complete();

        return result;
    }
}
```

This signature would mean you'd need to capture parameters rather than pass them:

```
public async Task<dynamic> SaveEntireEntity(EntityDTO entityDTO)
{
  return await _transactionProvider.ExecuteInTransactionAsync(
     async () => await SaveInTransaction(
         new { Name = entityDTO.Name, Address = entityDTO.Address, Age = entityDTO.Age }));
}
```

Once you're using the strongly-typed `Func<Task<T>>` instead of `Delegate` in your method signature, you can create an overload for `ExecuteInTransactionAsync` as such:

```
public async Task ExecuteInTransactionAsync(Func<Task> function)
{
    using (var scope = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeAsyncFlowOption.Enabled))
    {
        await (function()).ConfigureAwait(false);
        scope.Complete();
    }
}
```

which can be used as such:

```
public async Task UpdateEntireEntity(UpdateEntityDTO entityDTO)
{
  await _transactionProvider.ExecuteInTransactionAsync(
    async () => await UpdateInTransaction(
        new { Name = entityDTO.Name, Address = entityDTO.Address, Age = entityDTO.Age }));
}

private async Task UpdateInTransaction(dynamic dto)
{
  await UpdateName(dto.Name);
  await UpdateAddress(dto.Address);
  await UpdateAge(dto.Age);
}
```

Comment: I'm honored to have you answered on my question. I've read some posts from you on this topic but I still have a hard time wrapping my head around it. I would like to avoid introducing changes to the existing code base, I think there should be no problem introducing your idea for `Update` and reusing it later if such moment occurs. What do you think?

Comment: You could add in the overload and try it without changing the other code. I'm not entirely sure which way the overload resolution will go if given a lambda returning `Task<T>` - would it choose the `Func<Task>` or the `Delegate`?

Comment: I've tested your exact suggestion - `public async Task ExecuteInTransactionAsync(Func<Task> function)` with the current code, it seems like there is no ambiguity, the compiler is also fine. I think to take advantage of this approach. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

You can change

```
private async Task<dynamic> UpdateInTransaction(dynamic dto)
{
  await UpdateName(dto.Name);
  await UpdateAddress(dto.Address);
  await UpdateAge(dto.Age);

  return await Task.FromResult<dynamic>(null);
}
```

to

```
private async Task<dynamic> UpdateInTransaction(dynamic dto)
{
  await UpdateName(dto.Name);
  await UpdateAddress(dto.Address);
  await UpdateAge(dto.Age);

  return null;
}
```

Comment: Yeah... I've seen both approaches. The problem for me is that in general - a method that shouldn't return anything return something, even if it's a null.

Comment: @Leron Can you change the signature of `UpdateInTransaction` to `async Task` without the `<dynamic>`?

Comment: Yes, I've played around a lot with those. Most of the time I got exception that I can cast `Tasks.VoidResult` to `Tasks.Task`.